# Microsoft Access 2000 Switch Views at Runtime

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm creating a form programatically that has a ComboBox that is populated with a list of options.  On selecting an option, I'd like the form to be populated with various controls.

At the moment I'm achieving it by:

```
FormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
DoCmd.Close acForm, FormName, acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName, acDesign
' Do Work to create controls
DoCmd.Close acForm, FormName, acSaveYes
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName, acNormal
```

The problem is, I'm going to have many temporary forms saved in my database.  So as I see it there are two options for me,

1. Switch to design view without having to save the form
2. Be able to delete the form when I'm done with it

I've tried putting

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acForm, FormName
```

in the OnClose, and OnUnload triggers, but it results in a "You can't delete the object 'Form1' while it is open" error

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your options result in a limited number of controls on the form? In other words, would it be possible to have all the controls you need created ahead of time, just not Visible? Then all you would need to do is show and position what is needed without having to re-create everything from scratch.

Comment: While that is _possibly_ a solution, as there is a maximum number of controls on the screen.  I don't think it would be a very nice solution.  Though, the more I'm developing for Access the less elegant the solutions I'm having to come up with are.

Comment: @busk Don't forget you can change a control's properties without switching to design view, such as a control's control source. I do something similar with a form I use for reporting. You can choose from a list of reports, and the form will turn on/off from a list of controls what is needed for the parameters of the selected report. This form currently has 330 controls on it.

Comment: Thanks,  I'm probably going to end up going either this route, or scratch the idea all together.  I'm in the process of converting a MS Access database to be just front end only, followed by making a web interface.  So I'm thinking I must just create these last few forms first.